# Why i cant access alias in subquery?

Tags: sql

For example:

if i try

```
     select job from (select ename as "name", job from emp)
```

works but

```
     select name from (select ename as "name", job from emp)
```

don't.

even this doesn't work.

```
     select a.name from (select ename as "name", job from emp) a
```

Comment: Not `) a`, but `) AS a`

Comment: Your first code sample will throw an error in many database engines.  Which one are you using?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos depends on the variant of SQL. Works for me without the AS

Comment: Your last query works quite nicely ([demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d33c/4)).

Comment: @AlexandreSantos with AS i get:
 ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
without AS i get:
 ORA-00904: "A"."NAME": invalid identifier

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL Server 2008R2

```
SELECT
    A.Name

FROM
    (SELECT
        FormStatus AS [Name],
        FormStatusCodeID
    FROM
        CodeFormStatus) AS A
```

works as expected.(Used existing table for testing)

Comment: used SELECT A.Name FROM (SELECT ename AS "Name", job FROM emp) AS A
just as you wrote, didnt work.
I really cant understand why

Answer (score 0):

`select a.name from (select ename as "name", job from emp) as a`